# Why to use () => in react even if the result is working without it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why to use '()=>this.handleClick' in ReactJS even if its working in this also like 'this.handleClick' directly ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
 handleClick = () => {
  console.log("Hi there, user!");
};

render() {
return (
  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <a href="https://google.com">
        Click this text to see the event bubbling    
    </a>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick}>Click me</button>    
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: its helpful if u want to pass any parameter to the function

Comment: The [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) part of the documentation is a good read to get a better grasp of the nuances.

Comment: Arrow functions capture `this`, otherwise you have to bind it. Your `handleClick` function does not use `this` so that's why it works.

Comment: This is related to the scope binding of 'this'. More details on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`()=>this.handleClick()` This is used when there is a need to supply an argument to that function.
Like, 
`onClick={(data)=>this.handleClick(data)}`

If there is no need of passing argument you can use 
`this.handleClick`